# Windows Move Command (All except one file)

Tags: windows, command-line

Currently I'm moving all files from one dir to another using the *Move* command in Windows, outlined below:

```
move "path\*" "path2\"
```

Is there anyway to exclude one file from "path*" using move ?

Any other advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I now realise that * is a wildcard and for my purpose all I had to change was:

move "path*.txt" "path2\"

This moves all text files from the path and leaves any other file.